# Oracle: Update Every Row in a Table based off an Array

Tags: oracle, plsql, dbeaver

So i'm trying to create some seed data for a database that uses zip codes. I've created an array of 22 arbitrary zip code strings, and i'm trying to loop through the array and update one of the zips to every row in a table. Based on what I read and tried (I'm a 1st year, so I'm probably missing something), this should work, and does when I just output the array value based on the count of the table. this issue is in the row id subquery. When I run it in my console, it doesn't throw any errors, but it never completes and I think it's stuck in an infinite loop. How can I adjust this so that it will update the field and not get stuck?

```
declare
    t_count NUMBER;
    TYPE zips IS VARRAY(22) OF CHAR(5);
    set_of_zips zips;
    i NUMBER;
    j NUMBER :=1;
BEGIN
    SELECT count(*) INTO t_count FROM T_DATA;
    set_of_zips:= zips('72550', '71601', '85920', '85135', '95451', '90021', '99611', '99928', '35213', '60475', '80451', '80023', '59330', '62226', '27127', '28006', '66515', '27620', '66527', '15438', '32601', '00000');
    FOR i IN 1 .. t_count  LOOP
        UPDATE T_DATA
        SET T_ZIP=set_of_zips(j)
        ---
        WHERE           rowid IN (
            SELECT ri FROM (
                SELECT rowid AS ri 
                FROM T_DATA
                ORDER BY T_ZIP
            )
        ) = i;
        ---
        j := j + 1;
        IF j > 22 
            THEN 
                j := 1;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    COMMIT;
end;
```

Comment: SELECT count(*) INTO t_count FROM T_DATA is getting the entire row count. You are then looping once per row (for every row in the table). One would expect a single row operation inside this loop, but you are updating every row in the table... which means if there are 10000 rows, you are doing 10000*10000 or 100,000,000 row updates. See my answer below for a simple alternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need PL/SQL for this.

```
UPDATE t_data
SET t_zip = DECODE(MOD(ROWNUM,22)+1,
1,'72550',
2,'71601',
3,'85920',
4,'85135',
5,'95451',
6,'90021',
7,'99611',
8,'99928',
9,'35213',
10,'60475',
11,'80451',
12,'80023',
13,'59330',
14,'62226',
15,'27127',
16,'28006',
17,'66515',
18,'27620',
19,'66527',
20,'15438',
21,'32601',
22,'00000')
```

Comment: Thank You So Much, @PaulW !!!! This worked and the job finished almost instantly. I also spent some time reading about DECODE (im a js guy working with Java now) and got a much better idea of what it was doing, so now I have that tool in my SQL belt. Cheers!!!